# Invalid identifier Oracle SQL Dev

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a stupid problem, I know, but I don't see my error(s)...

Here is my SQL code when I create my tables

```
CREATE TABLE Nageur
(   NumN number not null,
    NomN varchar2(30) null,
    PrenomN varchar2(30) null,
    AnDateNaiss number null, 
    Nationalite varchar2(10),
    Genre varchar2(1),
    Pole varchar2(50),
        CONSTRAINT PK_Nageur PRIMARY KEY (NumN));

    CREATE INDEX I_FK_Nageur_Club
        ON Nageur (NumClub ASC);

CREATE TABLE Club
(   NumClub number NOT NULL,
    NomClub varchar2(40) NULL, 
    Region varchar2(40) NULL,
    Departement varchar2(40) NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Club PRIMARY KEY (NumClub));
```

The lines that gives me errors

```
ALTER TABLE Nageur ADD (
CONSTRAINT FK_nageur_club
FOREIGN KEY (NumClub)
REFERENCES Club (NumClub));

ALTER TABLE Competition ADD (
CONSTRAINT FK_competition_piscine
FOREIGN KEY (NumP)
REFERENCES Piscine (NumP));
```

And here my errors on Oracle

```
Erreur commençant à la ligne: 97 de la commande -
ALTER TABLE Nageur ADD (
CONSTRAINT FK_nageur_club
FOREIGN KEY (NumClub)
REFERENCES Club (NumClub))
Rapport d'erreur -
Erreur SQL : ORA-00904: "NUMCLUB" : identificateur non valide
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Erreur commençant à la ligne: 102 de la commande -
ALTER TABLE Competition ADD (
CONSTRAINT FK_competition_piscine
FOREIGN KEY (NumP)
REFERENCES Piscine (NumP))
Rapport d'erreur -
Erreur SQL : ORA-00904: "NUMP" : identificateur non valide
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

And I don't see my error because NumClub and NumP exist...

Comment: NumClub  does not exist in Nageur table. You should even get a failure while creating the index I_FK_Nageur_Club

Comment: Oh yes that's right, didn't see this error too ...

Comment: Okay I can see the errors now ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the column `NumClub` in the table `Nageur`.

Once fixed this, all the statements, except the one on `Competition` , should run fine; the statement on `Competition`  can not be verified, not knowing the structure of this table.